# Is TestNG eclipse plugin version workability dependent on TestNG jar version in pom.xml?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng, testng-eclipse

Do the version have to be compatible? How do I find the compatibles?

Comment: The eclipse plugin is supposed to work with the most of testng versions.

Answer (score 1):

since testng-eclipse 6.9.10, testng versions below 6.5.1 are not supported any more, please see more details in the change log: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/blob/master/CHANGES.md#6910

Answer (score -1):

I hope below link helps you..

http://testng.org/doc/download.html

Now a days all are Eclipse 3.4 and more.. you can happily use latest testng dependent in pom.xml

Thanks